# Angular 2: Unable to install ng2-material

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to use data table with [**ng2-material**](https://github.com/justindujardin/ng2-material) library as following:

```
<md-data-table [selectable]="true">
  <thead>
    <tr md-data-table-header-selectable-row>
      <th class="md-text-cell">Material</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let material of materials" md-data-table-selectable-row [selectable-value]="material.id">
      <td class="md-text-cell">{{ material.name }}</td>
      <td>{{ material.quantity }}</td>
      <td>{{ material.price }}</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</md-data-table>
```

But Angular2 doesn't recognize the `md-data-table` tags. I've found out that I don't have the @angular2-material in my `node_modules` directory. Decided to install it by command:

> npm install --save ng2-material

But somehow, some errors appears in the console:

> +-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/upgrade@2.2.0
>   `-- ng2-material@0.8.1`
>   -- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY @angular/upgrade@2.2.0
>
> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\ch
>   okidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@
>   1.0.15: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"
>   })
>
> npm WARN @angular/router@3.2.0 requires a peer of @angular/upgrade@2.2.0 but non
>   e was installed.

**Any help appreciated.**

Comment: They're just warnings: do you have have any actual error messages or other problems at build or run time?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Nope, but the angular2-material is not installed in my app folder, it doesnt recognize the tags, so I bet its not downloaded properly... Or that code is deprecated? I used code from this site: https://justindujardin.github.io/ng2-material/#/components/data-table

Comment: It's not supposed to be in your app folder, it should be placed in `node_modules`. How have you added it to your actual project, beyond just the `npm install`?

Comment: @jonrsharpe Yeah, I have `node_modules` directory, with a lot of stuff inside. But the data table from that site requires an `@angular2-material` module, which actually doesnt exist in the `node_modules` folder. But it supposed to be here, since Ive installed it...

Comment: Isn't `@angular2-material` a completely different package to `ng2-material`.

Answer (score 0):

try this command it works for me

```
$ npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk
```

then

```
$ ng add @angular/material
```